# Radeon HD 7990 in Ubuntu 12.04 and above

Tags: gpu

I suppose this is a simple question...

Will a Radeon HD 7990 dual gpu card work properly in Ubuntu 12.04 and above?

I've tried searching the net to no avail unfortunately.  The price of the top of the line card has dropped considerably where it is worth looking at especially with Steam games getting better by the month.  Will Crossfire on this card work?

Answer (score 1):

yes it will be quad crossfire.Recommend,first to install driver,and activate driver with just one dual card(inside desktop).
when is just one dual card inside then last step of installation driver is:
sudo amdconfig --initial -f --adapter=all, but dont use that command if you have two dual cards already installed!

Then add 2nd card into motherboard,boot,and add crossfire chain ,and activate crossfire,and then reboot.Also check what crossfire speed yours motherboard support,regardless OS.

Be sure that IOMMU option if u have it in BIOS is disabled!
As with IOMMU =on ,both single and dual cards will not work in crossfire,regardless dual,triple,or quad crossfire ,its like that,for now.